# How would I go about creating the hover animation for the nav in this website?

Tags: javascript, css

The website is https://ceremonycoffee.com/. How do I replicate their nav hover animation with the underline? I can't really find it in their inspect element. Also, is it made from CSS or Javascript? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in full css, see this snippet :

```css
h2 > a {
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h2 > a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

h2 > a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

h2 > a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<h2><a href="#">My Link</a></h2>
```

It relies on the `::before` pseudo element. You set its horizontal scale to zero, add a transition property so that when hovered it transforms smoothly to the full link scale.

Source and explanation : [Animating Links Underline](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/css-trick-animating-link-underlines/)

Comment: the snippet does not work, but the link is meaningfull ;)

Comment: On what browser are you viewing it ? It does work for me (firefox)

Comment: Yes that's quite strange

Comment: The snippet's working for me but it doesn't work when I try implementing it into my own code. Here's my CSS

Comment: Where is your css ? Add a link to a jsfiddle or something.